# Can I keep warps when moving from Minecraft Paper to a mods preinstall?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-mods

I administer a Minecraft server for my daughter and her friends on Pebblehost that is currently running Paper 1.15.2 with a few plugins, including [`Essentials`](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/essentialsx.9089/). The community has created many warps. My daughter wants to be able to run mods.

Pebblehost offers preinstalls based on `curseforge`, `technic`, and `ftb`. My understanding is that I can't add plugins to these, or at least not `Essentials`. Is there any way to add mods without losing the warps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It *should* be possible from the information I found on Pebblehost's website. Despite the preinstall, Pebblehost still provides full FTP access. The problem here might be the server version, since you cannot select the version you want after selecting a preinstallation. You might want to contact Pebblehost to ensure whether the preinstallation can be made on Spigot (or whatever version you were using).

If that won't do, you can still install the mods manually, since you still have FTP access. I don't have much experience in modding Minecraft servers, but skimming through some tutorials, [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AEU4efZuPeI) seemed the best, so, I hope it helps.

Finally, this question is extremely specific depending on what hosting you use. I recommend you contact Pebblehost's support for this issue.